# is the pullback of the cohomology of a group to the cohomology of a subgroup surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, is $i^*(H^*(G)$) surjective onto the cohomology of $H$? $i$ is the inclusion of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: It may be clearer to use, e.g., $K$ for a subgroup, since you're using $H$* for cohomology.

Comment: What are you taking coefficients in?

Comment: I had in mind z coefficients and was looking for more explanatory answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret your question as asking about any coefficient module. Then the answer is no in general. For example,  for any $G$-module $M$ the $0$-th cohomology $H^0(G,M) = M^G$, the invariants of the group action. Then for $H \subseteq G$, the induced map on $0$-th cohomogy groups is just the inclusion of invariants $M^G \subseteq M^H$ since any invariant for $G$ will clearly be invariant for $H$. This is not in general surjective.

Answer (score 0):

No, the map $H^1(\mathbb Z)\xrightarrow{i^\ast} H^1(k\mathbb Z)\cong H^1(\mathbb Z)$ is multiplication by $k$. (I am assuming constant coefficients.)

Comment: Right but then what if the subgroup is pure? By pure I mean if some power of an element is in the subgroup then the element is also in the subgroup.